# How to join tables to create fluent laravel api for my project.

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Let's say i've four tables.

$products, $attributes, $tags, $categories

I am trying to join all of them to create one fluent api like the following.

```

```
[
 {
  "products": {
    product_name: "Shiny Shoes", <<<<---- Currently i can get one table to work.
    product_description: "These Are Shiny Shoes",
  "attributes": {
    attributes_name: null,
    attributes_description: null
 }
}
```

```

I am not able to join all four tables, i tried everything and still doesn't work.

Comment: So... what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried making relationships but when i try to do $products->attributes it gives me error method doesn't exist.

Comment: Please post the code, so we can help you.

Comment: you could try raw db queries: DB::raw('SQL query here')

Comment: right, but the issue with DB::raw is i've transformer class that transforms the collection into array and $products->all() doesn't work on the raw query.